# animation goes from left to right , but i expect it to go from right to left, why?

Tags: svg

I have the following svg animation, simple svg line animation:

```css
line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-dasharray: 190, 190;
  stroke-dashoffset: 190;
  animation: drawline 5s 0.5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes drawline {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 190;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="190" height="200" viewBox="0 0 44 75">
            <line stroke-dasharray="190" x1="0" y1="10" x2="190" y2="10" />
        </svg>
```

Now since my animation `drawline` says go from `stroke-dashoffset: 190` to `stroke-dashoffset: 0` , i expect this animation to be from right to left , but instead this animation goes from left to right, why ? can somebody please explain this ?

*NOTE* : this is a `why` question, not a how `to-do-this-question`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<line stroke-dasharray="190" x1="0" y1="10" x2="190" y2="10" />
```

should be

```
<line stroke-dasharray="190" x1="190" y1="10" x2="0" y2="10" />
```

x1 is the starting point, x2 is the end

```css
line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-dasharray: 190, 190;
  stroke-dashoffset: 190;
  animation: drawline 5s 0.5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes drawline {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 190;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="190" height="200" viewBox="0 0 44 75">
            <line stroke-dasharray="190" x1="190" y1="10" x2="0" y2="10" />
        </svg>
```